# Multiple objects inside variables, output them one by one with powershell

Tags: powershell, variables

I got a question, I've been searching high and low for this but cant find an answer (also my coding skills are zero to none)..
In powershell I have 2 variables, for example say $apples and $oranges.
They both contain a list of values that are not yet split and $oranges sometimes contains an empty value, like

```
$apples = red green blue yellow purple
$oranges = car bike   chair shirt
```

They are in the correct order

Now what I'm trying to achieve is split the values inside the variables, but only print those values inside $apples that have a value greater than 2 characters in $oranges

So that it skips "blue" because in $oranges that spot is empty and the output in the text file would become something like this:

Apples red
Oranges car

---

Apples green
Oranges bike

---

Apples yellow
Oranges chair

---

Apples purple
Oranges shirt

Is there any mastermind out there that could help me?

Comment: Perhaps you should rephrase your question. What type shall the vars have to have an empty spot? Can't grep the meaning of `only print those values inside $apples that have a value greater than 2 characters in $oranges`

Comment: Well the values inside both variables are in the same order, but some values inside the second variable are empty and contain just a space like " ".. So what i want is for example if the length of the third value inside $oranges is less than 2, it also ignores or skips the third value inside $apples.. Then i wanna write the output like first value of $apples and first value of $oranges, then second value of $apples and second value of $oranges, etc etc

Answer (score 2):

I edited your question to make any sense, you can't set a string containing spaces to a var without quoting. I still don't know what the meaning of that sentence is.

This script:

```
$apples = ("red green blue yellow purple").split(' ')
$oranges = ("car bike  chair shirt").split(' ')
for ($i=0;$i -le $apples.Length; $i++){
  if ($oranges[$i]){
    "Apples {0}" -f $apples[$i]
    "Oranges {0}" -f $oranges[$i]
    ""
  }
}
```

Returns this output:

```
>  .\SO_42469662.ps1
Apples red
Oranges car

Apples green
Oranges bike

Apples yellow
Oranges chair

Apples purple
Oranges shirt
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, you saved me so much headache man, thanks a million